# Enumerate returns index -1 resulting in ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, enumerate

I am trying to make a new column in my df which will be something like:

```
df["Signal"] = signalList
```

However, I get this error "Enumerate returns index -1 resulting in ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index". So I checked the len of my column:

```
print(len(df["Crossover"]))
```

This returns 8192. So I adjusted the code to print *x so I can see where it goes up to and I get *8191. How can I fix this? Cheers.

```
signalList = []
 for x,i in enumerate(df["Crossover"]):
print("*"+str(x))
if i == True:
    if df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] > df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
        signal = "Buy"
        signalList.append(signal)
    elif df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] < df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
        signal = "Sell"
        signalList.append(signal)
elif i != True:
    signal = "None"
    signalList.append(signal)
```

EDIT ****************************************************************************
I was wondering if you could tell me if it is possible to adjust my code below to take advantage of vectorized processing. As it is so much quicker. The first bit of code is my attempt and it kinda works and the loop below is how I want it to work exactly. The problem I am having is essentially I need the lines before the first buy/sell signal to be None in the "Position Column" However, I can't get the vectorized table to do that. Although it will accurately identify when to switch to long/short anything prior to the signal will be "Short"  because the condition returns False. I've not had any luck getting round this.

```
df["Position"] = np.where(df['Signal'].ne("None"),np.where(df[f'Signal'].eq("Buy"), "Long", "Short"), np.where(df["Position"].shift(1).eq(True), "Long", np.where(df["Position"].shift(1).eq(False), "Short", "None")))

for x,i in enumerate(df['Signal']):
    if i == "Buy":
        df.iloc[x, df.columns.get_loc('Position')] = "Long"
    elif i == "Sell":
            df.iloc[x, df.columns.get_loc('Position')] = "Short"
    else:
        if df["Position"].iloc[x-1] == "Long":
            df.iloc[x, df.columns.get_loc('Position')] = "Long"
        elif df["Position"].iloc[x-1] == "Short":
            df.iloc[x, df.columns.get_loc('Position')] = "Short"
        else:
            df.iloc[x, df.columns.get_loc('Position')] = "None"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably don't have correct indentation in your code, the correct one is

```
signalList = []
for x, i in enumerate(df["Crossover"]):
    print("*" + str(x))
    if i == True:
        if df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] > df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
            signal = "Buy"
            signalList.append(signal)
        elif df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] < df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
            signal = "Sell"
            signalList.append(signal)
    elif i != True:
        signal = "None"
        signalList.append(signal)
```

Second, the inner `if`-`elif` is without `else`; what about the case if

```
df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] == df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
```

I suppose there is a row in your `df` which satisfies *just this condition*.

Comment: The indentation was a copy and paste error I guess at least my code in atom is indented correctly. You are very much correct on your assumption of the problem so thankyou for that!.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your `for` loop consider the following:

```py
import numpy as np

df['signal']=np.where(df['Crossover'], np.where(df[f'EMA {emaShort}'].lt(df[f'EMA {emaLong}']), 'Sell', 'Buy'), 'None')
```

You will leverage the vectorized processing that way, which should make your code performing way better...

Comment: Whats this called so i can google? / can you give me the link to a good article?

Comment: what does the lt do?

Comment: `lt` - equivalent to `<`. For vectorized execution - this looks interesting: https://medium.com/hackernoon/speeding-up-your-code-2-vectorizing-the-loops-with-numpy-e380e939bed3 (look for `numpy`, as that's what's under the hood for `pandas`)

Comment: Cheers Ive put a edit in my code is there any chance you can have a look at it? I've hit a bit of a wall and as I am new to vectorized processing im a bit stuck.